# Custom sound in local Notification IONIC 3

Tags: javascript, audio, ionic-framework, ionic3, uilocalnotification

I want to change the default sound for local notification on android but it doesn't work

i tried to put the sound file into the project but when i run my app it play the default sound

[image]

also i tried to put on sound field a remote sound file but the same issue

```
this.localNotifications.schedule({
    text: 'Delayed ILocalNotification',
    at: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 3600),
    led: 'FF0000',
    sound: 'https://notificationsounds.com/soundfiles/15de21c670ae7c3f6f3f1f37029303c9/file-sounds-1085-definite.mp3',

 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sounds file where you placed is correct.

But when you build the Android app, it's location is different.

```
android_asset/www/assets/sounds/name.mp3
```

That is the location you need to specify

Of course this is used when you are using the `media` plugin, after the notification is received.

***EDIT***
This is no longer a viable solution. Refer docs for ionic, since there are ground breaking changes both in android and iOS

Comment: @Dev how did you do it using media plugin?

Comment: @LuckyAngelo please look into the version of ionic framework that you are using since there are many changes that had happened in many of the plugins

Comment: glad it helped!

Comment: Hello Kevin, how are you? I am also trying to play custom sound on the Local Notification in my Ionic 4 android app. Since I can't solve this issue, I'd like you to help me with it. Thank you.

Comment: What kind of notification service are you using?

Comment: I am using FCM.

Comment: There's a little bit of change, from ionic 3 since ionic 4 is out now and I am using ionic 4 now. But of course you could pass in on a file name with fcm notification object and put the same notification tone inside the assets folder and play it once the notification reaches the client

Comment: Thank you for your support. Excuse me, can you guide me through teamviewer since I don't have enough experience in Ionic 4?

Comment: I could surely help you? How do I contact you?

Comment: Thank you so much. You can contact me through email. webdevstar1222@gmail.com. I've done for Android 8.x. But it doesn't work for older version. Hope your reply.

Comment: I haven't tried the older versions though, my recent app is based on android 10

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out using the capacitor local notifications on any version of Android. To get the sound working you must create a channel. The link to all information about this is
https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/1146
When you get there checkout the comment made under @moderntechllc