# Ionic 4 local notification custom sound not working in android 10

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

I am building an Ionic 4 app and the Local Notification plugin custom sound was not working in android. Is just playing the default sound, and ignoring the sound

Comment: Can you share the code for the same? Also mention the sound file path

Comment: I am using local notification plugin of ionic native anh here is the code this.localNotifications.schedule({
  id: 1,
  text: 'Single ILocalNotification',
  sound: isAndroid? 'file://sound.mp3': 'file://beep.caf',
  data: { secret: key }
});

Comment: Check this link here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48708626/custom-sound-in-local-notification-ionic-3

Comment: I am creating ionic4+capacitor app so this is not working in my case